# Drawing several Rects

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw a visualization of the stack at certain points while executing a program, so some kind of rectangles, filled with an address and value and in some color, depending on some events. I'm using C++ with Qt.

Right now, my `Stackview` class holds all `StackItems` and then uses the `paintEvent` to draw all of those into my Dialog-window. This window isn't scrollable, so if the stack is bigger, I can't see all stack items or scroll down!

My question is should I use a `GraphicsView` and a `GraphicsScene` and add my Rects there or should I do something with a `QScrollArea`, I'm not sure, what fits my needs best and how to implement it?

The end result should be, that my Debugger can step through code line by line and update the stack, depending on the line.

Comment: Just draw everything on a widget, resize widget to fit the content and put the widget as a viewport to the scroll area.

Comment: I'd recommend just using QLabels with background colors and custom fixed sizes if possible. But regardless just add your widgets in the QHBoxLayout/QGridLayout of a QScrollArea and it should work. That's what layouts are for.